# How to store tokens on the client side using node js on backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm using passport.js for local authentication and express-session for managing session of a user but express-session is storing cookies on the client side. Since cookies are less secure, I want to send and receive jwt tokens in the client side but I don't know how to do that.
I'm using mongodb for the database, express framework and node js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express-session has lots of different storing solutions can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores).

For example, you can use MongoDB to store your session data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

In node.js

```
verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).send({
            auth: false, message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                auth: false,
                message: 'Fail to Authentication. Error -> ' + err
            });
        }
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });
}
```

Then add it to your router

```
var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
    });
    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, accessToken: token });
```

The client side

```
const data = { username, password }
    await axios.post(*usl, data, {
    }).then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken)
}, (error) => { console.log('error', error) });
```